# How to over write the existing header in drupal 8X

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, drupal-8

In default layout, there was header available. where the header source found how to over write the header file with custom css and html

Comment: This question is unclear at best.  Please rephrase.

Answer (score 1):

Enable twig debug info to see what part of page source is rendered from what template. Inside file:

```
sites/default/services.yml
```

Enable it like:

```
parameters:
  twig.config:
    debug: true
```

Clear the cache and then inspect page source and beside info of what template is used you'll also get suggestions on options to override that template file. So if you just copy file which is used (clear the cache)  Drupal will start using it instead of original one. But in case you want to use it only in specific situations (i.e. for some content type, for some node...) check those file name  suggestions.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates